# JAVA distinguish curved line from straight line

Tags: java, esri, polyline

I am having an issue where I am not sure how to tell if a given (com.esri.arcgis.geometry.Polyline) Polyline is straight or not. My code works for straight lines but does not for curved. My issues are that I am not sure how to get a list of points from the Polyline and not sure how to check if the line is straight once I get this list of points. Code below:

```
 else if (shape instanceof Polyline) {
                    Polyline line = (Polyline) shape;
                    Point lowerLeft = (Point) line.getEnvelope().getLowerLeft();
                    Point upperRight = (Point) line.getEnvelope().getUpperRight();
                    Point midpoint = GeometryUtil.getMidpoint(lowerLeft, upperRight);
                    midpoint.setSpatialReferenceByRef(ActiveMapContainer.getInstance()
                                                              .getMapBean().getSpatialReference());
                    GeometryUtil.projectLatLong(midpoint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of points on polyline using "getLength()" method.
You can obtain each point with "getPoint(int i)" method.

There are probably better methods, but I would check if line is straight that way:
1. Calculate the distance between first and last point.
2. Compare it to the whole polyline's length. If both are equal (possibly using some kind of acceptable difference in length - "delta"), assume the line is straight. If they are different by a factor bigger that "delta", assume the line is not straight.